# Have file name same as Makefile target name

Tags: makefile, gnu

I searched for other answers, but they doesn't match my question exactly..

I have a target and also a file with the same name (in one of the folders added to VPATH). Like so..

```
rajesh : hello.elf
    ld <some Options> hello1.o hello2.o rajesh.o

%.o : %.c
    cc <some options> -o $@ $<
```

It builds the .elf file fine. But then, it also tries to build a target "rajesh" again, and it takes some intrinsic rule, and tries to build a file "rajesh" from "rajesh.c". And fails. Eventhough it created the proper target already, it's a bit irritating to see a failure message. Any Advices?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your Makefile is a little strange. Does `hello.elf` exist before do making? If not, maybe you need a rule like:

```
hello.elf: dep1 dep2
    cmd <option> dep1 dep2 ...
```

If you want a file-independant target, just use `.PHONY`.

```
.PHONY: rajesh
```

Then, make will not try to check file named `rajesh`.